# interactive python wallpaper

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wallpaper

so I want to make an interactive wallpaper with python but I can't use the gif object directly and instead have to save it which makes it stutter or crash anyone know way to fix this?

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import ctypes
from time import sleep
from mouse import get_position as pos
gif = Image.open('giphy.gif')

while 1:
  for image in range(gif.n_frames):

    #gif=Image.new('RGBA',(1920,1080))
    #gif.paste(Image.open('3.png'),pos())
    gif.seek(image)
    gif.save(r'gif','PNG',quality=50)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, r'C:\Users\Me_\Documents\pyprojects\wallpaper\gif', 3)
```

I've tried importing it into bytes but I'm pretty new so I'm sure a lot of you could do better